# Proof of Kirchoff's second law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, voltage

There are 2 approaches I have stumbled to prove [Kirchhoff's second law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_circuit_laws):

1. Derive it from the conservation of energy.
2. You can derive that from "integral of E*ds = 0".

Can you show me a full or at least very convincing proof using both approaches?

Comment: The two approaches are equivalent - you go around a full circuit path and you have to have the same energy as when you started when you come back to where you started. Nothing magic. Please be more specific about what kind of 'convincing' you need.

Comment: The latter proof is _wrong_ if there are inductors involved, it basically only gives the right answer by accident. You need to use the full form of Faraday's Law.

Comment: jon custer - why the emf - voltage drop = 0? let's look at simple circuit with voltage source and resistor. How do you derive the results from these 2 approaches?

Comment: knzhou - can you explain more by an example?

Comment: @JonCuster tagging

Comment: @knzhou  tagging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer I propose for the 2nd way.
I'm for sorry for the bad paintings.

[image]